# How to make fixed size container inside container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make layout of app where main container will have 45% of device height and container inside main container should be of fix size.

I have written following code but inner container takes full height as its parent(main) container.

```
class TestContainer extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: 50,
          height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
          color: Colors.red
          child:Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.green
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong with this ?

Comment: Add a child to the second container.

Comment: Eg, Container (child: Text ("hello"),),

Comment: This won't fix the issue, you need to understand how constraints works in Flutter. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix it by wrapping it with a `Center` widget:

```
class TestContainer extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: 50,
          height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
          color: Colors.red,
          // wrap with a center widget
          child:Center(
            child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

*TO PLACE THE INNER CONTAINER AT THE BOTTOM CENTER*

```
class TestContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
      color: Colors.red,
      // wrap with a align widget
      child: Align(
        // set the alignment property
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Read more about Layout Constraints in Flutter here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: Thanks @Derek. Is there any way to position inner container to be bottom of main container. I tried `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,` but this seems to be not working.

Comment: You need to wrap the inner `Container` with an `Align` widget rather than using the `alignment` property. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestContainer extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
      width: 50,
      height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
      color: Colors.red,
      child:Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.green
                )
             )
           ] )
      ); }
}
```

Comment: I agree but there is multiple way  to do same  task.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Container's basic property is to consume the parents size... So in order to add `Container` as child to an another `Container` you simply nee to specify where you need the inner container to be displayed on outer container.. `otherwise the child container will grow to the size of its parent Container`.

```
Container(
    width: 400.0,
    height: 400.0,
    color: Colors.green,
    alignment: Alignment.center, // align your child's position.
    child: Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
```